# Accessing vectors' methods within a class

Tags: java

I have a class that contains several vectors. Each of these vectors too contain vectors. The fields within these classes contain setters and getters for private strings.

I have one main class in which all the vectors are contained. I instantiate this class, and I need to access the fields that have been set within the vectors.

If the structure is like:

```
public class a{
private Vector a, b, c;
}

private class b{
private Vector d, e, f;
}
```

All of those classes also have strings with setters and getters-- that is all.

Can I do something like this (assuming this object has vectors whose fields are populated--this is done in a separate part of the code with Digester, but I know this part is correct.)

```
a myObject = new a;
Vector b = this.b;
for(int i=0;i<b.size();i++){
    System.out.println(a.b.get(i).getmyString());
}
```

if so, how do I now access the methods within each class, b, whose vectors are d e and f?

Please help! :(

Comment: You have to use reflection. There are plenty of questions on this site about reflection; use the search box at the top right. :-)

Comment: Could you please give me a little more direction than that? I'm reading the oracle documents on reflection, but I don't quite understand still...

Comment: You should tell us if you are a good programmer or a student. @Chris Jester-Young is taking you to a difficult road but my felling is that you are not an expert and just beginning java and asking a very basic question about visibility of data members. Where does this problem come from ?

Comment: I'm a student... I've been given a pretty long programming task at a university. I don't really know Java incredibly well, and I just kinda need any direction. If you even have a link from which I can study that'd work too. I've been googling java reflection vector. I appreciate giving me at least some direction with the word reflection :)

Comment: Which code or question have you been given and what is your own creation/answer ? The code you sent is quite poor actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should create your vectors to be type-specific. Let's assume you're storing objects of the type `MyData` into them, so you would have this:

```
public class MyData {
    private String myStringValue;

    public String getMyStringValue() {
        return this.myStringValue;
    }

    public void setMyStringValue(String myStringValue) {
        this.myStringValue = myStringValue;
    }
}
```

Then you should have your Vectors like this:

```
private Vector<MyData> a, b, c;
```

When you have it initialized like this, you can do this to access your objects' values:

```
// Loop through all MyData objects stored in the Vector b
for(MyData myData : b){
    System.out.println(myData.getMyStringValue());
}
```

As an afterthought, why use a `Vector`? You probably don't need Vector's synchronicity, so you would be better off using an `ArrayList`.

```
private List<MyData> b = new ArrayList<MyData>(); // populate the arraylist with objects
```

Also you would benefit more from studying basic OO stuff about encapsulation (= the getters and setters in my examples). Forget reflection for now and save that to the near future when you have the basics all sorted out.